# AdMob Mediation, Only Works For AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have AdMob mediation working and it serves AdMob ads fine but when I put in an active ID for MMedia, or MobFox, I get requests but 0 fill. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the libraries and mediation adapter libraries for those other ad networks in your app as well.